# How to limit float Value in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmediaitem

Now i am trying to get the length of Songs in iOS.

```
- (NSString *)returnofTotalLength
{
    float duration = [[self.player.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] floatValue]/60.0f;
    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",duration];;
    NSString *totalLength = [length stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@":"];

    return totalLength;
}
```

above codes is the total length of song that show like `5:90`.
You know that `5:90` can't be true because `60` seconds is `1` minute.

It's should be `6:30`.

So i want to limit that value for `1 minute (60 seconds).`

How can i do it Please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got answer for my own question.
Thanks for other answers. :)

```
NSTimeInterval currentProgress = [[self.player.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] floatValue];

    float min = floor(currentProgress/60);
    float sec = round(currentProgress - min * 60);

    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", (int)min, (int)sec];
    return time;
```

That will return `NSString` with Complete Format.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple math. Pseudocode:

```
minutes = (int)(seconds / 60);
rest    = seconds % 60;
result  = minutes:rest
```

Objc:

```
int seconds   = 150;
int minutes   = (int)(seconds / 60);
int rest      = seconds % 60;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", minutes, rest];
```

Answer (score 1):

do following :

```
min=(int)duration/60;
sec=duration%60;
```

than append minutes and second

Answer (score 1):

If your time crosses to hours then you can go for this :

```
NSInteger seconds = duration % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (duration / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = duration / (60 * 60);
NSString *result = nil;

result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];
```